# Undefined property name in dynamic variable of a class

Tags: php

I have the below code that returns error
`"Undefined property: Test::$todayDate()"`
the code is

```php
    public function todayDate() 
    {
        return date("Y-m-d");
    } 
    
    public function test_func()
    { 
        $func = "todayDate()";
        echo $this->$func; // this returns error 
        echo $this->{$func}; // this returns error 
    }
```

I'm expecting to get a return from the main function

Comment: It returns the same error

Comment: Your function's name is `todayDate`, not `todayDate()`. When you need to invoke it you can use the parentheses `echo $this->$func();` https://3v4l.org/PTP0I

Answer (score 1):

Your function's name is `todayDate, not todayDate()`. When you need to invoke it you can use the parentheses
echo $this->$func();